# Weird scrollbar on "Report this Ad" popup

Tags: bug, status-planned, design, advertising

The "Report Ad" popup has a weird and disabled scrollbar on the right side:

> [image: Report Ad]

Windows 10, Firefox 94.0.2 (64-bit)

Comment: @ARogueAnt. other similar popups (e.g. [in review queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Doii.png)) don't have scrollbars.

Comment: No repro from me. What browser and OS?

Comment: @CaveJohnson firefox. No repro in Chrome though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, we were able to reproduce it and will fix it. We'll keep this post updated with the status.

Comment: @JD-Stack in that case, isn't status-planned the more appropriate tag?

Comment: @Luuklag - You're fast! I needed to set it to `status-review` so it triggers the creation of a ticket, now changing it to `status-planned`

Comment: Haha good point @JD-Stack

Comment: @JD-Stack [such ticket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKRJ4.png)? ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 - nah, more something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyNt5zm3U_M)